# Grouping all locations into one location

Tags: sql, sql-server, teradata

So right now I have 36 bakeries - all with their respective bakery names. We also have them numbered as well. I want to group **35** of the bakeries together to find out their sales. I can pull them each individually but is it possible to pull them all together and call it number 35 for example?

```
 ----------- 
  LOCATION  
  1         
  2         
  15        
  17        
  53        
  68        
  76        
  81        
  173       
  213       
  215       
  259       
  560
```

Ideally, I'd like to group all the stores above and call it 35 Bakeries.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  So would an accurate database tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an aggregation query:

```
select 35, count(*), sum(sales)
from t
where location in (1, 2, 15, . . . );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to get the sales of your top 35 bakeries.

```
select '35' as bakery_name, sum(sales) from bakery t1
inner join 
(select distinct row_number() over (order by location) as rn, location from bakery) t2 on t2.location = t1.location
where t2.rn <= 35
```